# Dataflow pubsub IO has zero throughput despite messages being published

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a streaming system setup where Dataflow is consuming messages from a pubsub topic and eventually writing the data to a Postgres database. The individual messages that are being received from pubsub are being batched into an array before being inserted into Postgres. The batching logic utilizes [GroupIntoBatches](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/groupintobatches/), which underneath the hood, contains some stateful DoFns.

The outline of the Dataflow pipeline is as follows:

1. [Fused step 1] PubsubSourceIO - reads from a pubsub subscription
2. [Fused step 1] Some simple transformation logic
3. [Fused step 2] Simple filter
4. [Fused step 2] Assign a constant key e.g. `ParDo(Map(lambda x: ("constant-key", x)))`
5. [Fused step 2] Use `GroupIntoBatches` to either wait for 10 elements to collect, or 1 second to elapse, before letting the data through to the next PTransform
6. [Fused step 2] Write to postgres - insert an array of elements into a fixed postgres table

This pipeline has been running healthily for over 3-4 months now. However, we recently started inserting a large volume of data into Postgres using a completely separate system to backfill historical data. This backfill has caused degradation in data freshness across all stages of the pipeline. While a hand-wavy reasoning makes sense in that the database was getting overloaded, as such, back pressure built up to cause things to process more slowly (we set a max of 2 workers), I'm looking for a rigorous explanation as to why it's happening.

Some stats

- cpu utilization was healthy at less than 40%
- mem was healthy with only half the available 15gb of mem being utilized (when it was 1 worker). Dataflow bumped it up to 2 workers, while still maintaining 50% mem utilization

My main area of confusions are

1. Around 1 hour after the backfill job kicked off, the **source pubsub IO started to have zero output collections**. This basically means that the pubsub source was no longer reading in messages, and we further verified this with pubsub subscription stats where unacked messages started to build up for the same period. What could cause this? (looking for a non hand-wavy explanation)

[image: image showing zero throughput between 6am and 8am] There
were definitely messages being published to pubsub during this time
(confirmed by looking at pubsub message sent and publish stats)

2. The 2 images below show the input and output elements of the `GroupIntoBatches` PTransform. How is it possible that during the period of ~6am - ~8am where there were ***no input elements***, but there were still output elements at 6:10am and 6:45am? This somewhat implies that there was input collections that were "accumulated" in this PTransform from previously where there were still input, and those collections sat inside the PTrasnform waiting before getting processed at seemingly random intervals. Given that this is a `GroupIntoBatches` PTransform which does actually have a timer to release data, it could make sense, however, the gaps between the spikes in output elements are  1 hour apart, which is drastically different from the 1 second that I set for `max_buffering_duration_secs`

[image]
[image]

Some other chart that could be useful showing "Timers pending by stage" and "Timers processed by stage", though I'm not sure what both of these represent despite reading through the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf?&_ga=2.80836887.-1459783534.1662458562#timers). Both the purple and teal lines represent the fused step that contains `GroupIntoBatches`

[image]

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: What does your data freshness look like? I had a pipeline once, where the freshness was high and thus dataflow decided to stop ingesting until the already ingested data was processed (sorry for the hand-wavy answer)